# direct spread spectrum

Tags: digital-communications

I am studying the DSSS method and I have a question. For example, the emitter and the receiver use a $c_1$ sequence for spreading of length $L$. An eavesdropper uses a $c_2 $sequence of length $L$. We have $c_1 \neq c_2$. The transmission parameters are known to the eavesdropper: modulation, bandwidth, carrier frequency,....

Is it possible for the eavesdropper to find the sent message using $c_2$?

Answer (score 1):

No, using the sequence $c_2$, the eavesdropper cannot, in general, determine  the sent message. There are too many nuances for an adequate discussion of this problem on this forum, including how different are $c_1$ and $c_2$, and is it possible that $c_2$ is just a *cyclic* shift of $c_1$. In a direct-sequence spread-spectrum *multiple-access* system, many users share the channel and the receiver using $c_k$ as the spreading signal must contend with signals using $c_1, c_2, \cdots$ as spreading sequences appearing as multiple-access interference, and must discriminate against them. Here of course the spreading sequences are carefully chosen to minimize the multiple-access interference.